# View with pagination to have a single url per pagination page

Tags: views, panels, paging

I was doing a View for a last news from a site, but those news won't be accesible from outside, so only will be able to see the content by the view.

This view has a Pagination, and is printed as page. The problem is that I need to implement the facebook comment plugin, and I need that every page listed by the pagination, to have a unique url, I thought that it could be the same as the node url.

I tried by doing something with panes, but I could't override the View page. I'm Using Drupal 7 and the lasted version of views.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The url's are unique. If the page view has a url of `/news`, then each page can be referenced individually as `/news?page=0` for the first page, `/news?page=1` for the second page and so on.

Comment: Very True, this is it :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but with the facebook comment plugin, it reeds only the /news part, withouth the url arguments.
Maybe a problem with the facebook social plugin?